# how to show the group header on each page in telerik reporting Q3

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I have created a report in Telerik Q3.

While showing a second page, I have a problem:

The group header (same data) is set to repeat on each page, but I have to show a different group header on each page.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: very unclear what you are asking. please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

According to this response from [Telerik support](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-repeat-group-header-on-each-page-with-table-crosstable), this isn't possible:

> When PrintOnEveryPage is set to true for the Group Header/Footer, the sections on each page are always identical. The section is processed only the first time and afterwards a copy of it is printed on the rest of the pages, so distinguishing between them is not possible.